# awakeFromInsert vs. setting default value in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data

What is the difference between setting a default value for a Core data entities property in the Data Model Inspector vs. using awakeFromInsert() to set initial values?

Does one get called before the other? Can one overwrite the other? Is there a difference between a default value and an initial value?

Thanks

Comment: At least two of your Qs can be answered simply by trying.

Comment: Okay so i did a quick test and it seems that awakeFromInsert() gets called after the default value has been set and overrides it. So is there any difference between setting a value in awakeFromInsert as opposed to setting a default value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you want to set a date property to the date that the object was created. You can't really do that with a default value, but you can do it with an awake from insert.

Say you need to create a related entity for the object, you can't really do this with a default value, but you can from this method.

Default values are useful for when you want to allow a lightweight migration, as it gives an initial value if there is none for the previous model version, but for anything more involved, you want to use this method.